# Java - Run SWT dependent Program without SWT installed

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I have a java program, that includes `org.eclipse.swt` libraries like "Display" and "Shell"

One of the first things this program does is:

```
private void authenticationFlow() {
    Display display = new Display();

    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    final Browser browser;
    //some other code here
}
```

I exported this program to a runnable jar file and can run it just fine on my PC.

However, when trying to run it on a PC without eclipse installed, the Program does not start. No Exceptions whatsoever. It simply exits and does not run the rest of the code.

I tried to debug by creating a bunch of alert boxes like this:

```
private void authenticationFlow() {
    popAlertBox(AlertType.INFORMATION, "Nice", "Something happened", "Starting auth");
    Display display = null;
    try {
        display = new Display();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        popAlertBox(AlertType.ERROR, "Oh oh", "Something went wrong", e.getMessage());
    }
    popAlertBox(AlertType.INFORMATION, "Nice", "Something happened", "created display");
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    popAlertBox(AlertType.INFORMATION, "Nice", "Something happened", "created shell");
    final Browser browser;
    GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
    gridLayout.numColumns = 3;
    try {
        shell.setLayout(gridLayout);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        popAlertBox(AlertType.ERROR, "Shell error", "Could not instantiate Shell: ", e.getMessage());
    }
    //rest of code
```

And

```
private void popAlertBox(AlertType type, String title, String header, String contentText) {
    Alert alert = new Alert(type);
    alert.setTitle(title);
    alert.setHeaderText(header);
    alert.setContentText(contentText);
    alert.setX(GUIMain.getStageX() + GUIMain.getWidth()*0.4);
    alert.setY(GUIMain.getStageY()+ GUIMain.getHeight()*0.4);
    alert.showAndWait();
}
```

I end up seeing the "Starting auth" AlertBox, and that's it, the program exits right after.
I never reach the "created display" AlertBox.

So I figured it has to do with SWT itself.

Now my question is

```
1. Is this really directly related to SWT or am I misunderstanding something.
2. If it is, how can I have this program run on a PC without eclipse installed?
```

EDIT:

I use maven for all dependencies
here is an image of my libraries, including swt
[image]

I have tried surrounding my method which is called in a try catch like so:

```
        try{
            authenticationFlow();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            popAlertBox(AlertType.ERROR, "oh oh", "Something went wrong", e.getMessage());
        }
        popAlertBox(AlertType.INFORMATION, "Nice", "Something happened", "If you see this then something is in fact happening. final popup");
```

And NONE of those two popups are displayed. Not the one inside the catch block and the one afterwards neither.

i added following dependencies inside my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
        <artifactId>swt</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0-v3346</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64</artifactId>
        <version>4.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

and it is still not running on the pc, which does not have eclipse installed

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a program which is designed to have a ui written in SWT the best way is to provide the SWT library in the classpath of the application. This does not mean that you have to provide a whole eclipse. Eclipse is also just using SWT as the library for the ui.
Just grab the SWT jars and put them onto the classpath and the program should start presenting you a window which is expressed in the line `Shell shell = new Shell(display)`.

Adding SWT using Maven:

```
<properties>
  <swt.version>4.3</swt.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64</artifactId>
        <version>${swt.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86</artifactId>
        <version>${swt.version}</version>
        <!-- To use the debug jar, add this -->
        <classifier>debug</classifier>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86</artifactId>
        <version>${swt.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64</artifactId>
        <version>${swt.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64</artifactId>
        <version>${swt.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This will add SWT for every platform. You can also just add the one you need to build for.

When building the application into a "fat-jar" please make sure all the dependencies are provided.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195887/discussion-on-answer-by-arnonuem-java-run-swt-dependent-program-without-swt-in).